# Nested white-space nowrap/normal behaves strange

Tags: html, css, whitespace, nowrap

I've used `white-space: nowrap` and `display: inline-block` to force two elements on the same row, then set `White-space: normal` inside those elements to allow the text inside to wrap normally.

The problem is that for some reason the text won't wrap until the width of the viewport is smaller than ONE of the elements - not both.

I've created a fiddle to explain this further: https://jsfiddle.net/krkb8d9L/1/. Notice how you need to shrink the window to 100px (the width of the left most element) LESS than you normally would before the text starts wrapping.

Can someone explain why this is happening? It seems to be consistent across browsers as well. I'd obviously expect the text to start wrapping as soon as it doesn't fit (like it would if the elements were floated for example).

Comment: I have a feeling this has to do with the esoteric 'line-box` which I don't completely grasp / understand and how it interacts with the parent container and that's what dictates what happens on wrapping.

Comment: I think that it maybe has to do with the CSS render tree being laid out from the inside, outwards. i.e. the leaf node are laid out first, then placed in their container elements, then the container-containers etc, all the way up to the root node. That order's necessary to make things like vertical alignment work sanely. In that case, the inline-block would be laid out, taking the full width of its container first, then only subsequently would the `white-space:nowrap` kick in, forcing the wide inline-block to be on the same line as its predecessor.